# Count input type text fields with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with a lot of text fields and hidden input fields.
Now I am trying to count those input fields of type text, but I can't get it to work.

I am using the following code:

```
    var subtagid = document.getElementById('subtags').getElementsByTagName('input').getAttribute("text").length;
var inputs = document.getElementById('subtags').getElementsByTagName('input').length;
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)
{
    if(inputs[i].getAttribute(‘type’)==‘text’)
    {
        subtagid++;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: You should definitely not use weird quotes in code. And you only need `var` the first time.

Comment: You're looking for `.getAttribute("text")` instead of `type` but even that won't work since you're chaining that to a method that returns a list. Additionally, you're retrieving the `length` on `inputs` too soon, so you can't iterate over `inputs[i]`. Make it simple! `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]').length;` (you can replace `document` with an ID selector if needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to count all the text elements by using `querySelectorAll`.

```js
const count = document.querySelectorAll('#subtags input[type=text]').length;
```

Iterating over the elements is also possible.

```js
for (let input of document.querySelectorAll('#subtags input[type=text]')) {
    // Do something with the input.
}
```

You can use any other valid CSS selector as well.

Comment: would this count all the fields in the whole document or just in one form?

Comment: This will count all the text input fields inside of an element with the ID of "subtags".

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a `querySelectorAll` because the default type of `input` is `text`. In order to get the correct number you have to check `type` of the inputs and either `filter` and get the `length` or iterate and add to `subtagid`:

```
text_inputs = inputs.forEach(input => input.type === "text" && subtagid++);
```

```js
    var subtagid = 0,
    
    parent = document.querySelector("#subtags"),
    inputs = Array.from(parent.querySelectorAll("input")),
    text_inputs = inputs.forEach(input => input.type === "text" && subtagid++);

console.dir(subtagid);
```

```html
<section id="subtags">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="text">

<input type="button">
<input type ="text">
<input type="text">
<input>
</section>
<hr/>

<small> there are <strong>4</strong> Text Boxes </small>
<hr/>

<output>

</output>
```

Comment: @Addis uh. it's not wrong because that's literally what I said in my answer.

Comment: @Addis I don't mean to sound hostile here, but I believe you're wrong. The default input without a type defined in markup I believe isn't grabbed by a selector. Feel free to try it.

Comment: You made much sense now, though I don't think that's what the OP intended to do. Sorry for the misunderstanding, anyway.